# Need better fix for black screen after signing in to Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, black-screen-of-death

Issue started 2 days ago (8/11/23). I have Windows 10 and there was Windows Update installations recently (8/8/23) which I think might have caused the issue.

After logging in with my password at the initial sign-in before we reach the desktop screen, there is around a 5 minute black screen with only a mouse cursor showing. After 5 minutes the desktop shows up as usual. Restarting with Safe Mode doesn't have the black screen issue.

Things I tried before the latest solution I used:

1. Windows + Ctrl + Shift + B
2. Windows + P
3. Updating Drivers
4. Turning off Fast Startup
5. Malwarebytes + Adwcleaner + Windows Defender/Offline Defender full scans
6. DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
7. sfc /scannow
8. chkdsk /scan

The last thing I tried, which I found from a post in 2016, is stopping and disabling from startup a service called "App Readiness". This currently is working but the post mentioned and I am also experiencing it is that by disabling/stopping App Readiness, you wont be able to have Windows Updates. Even the post I read it from said that it is only a temporary fix and he will post again if there is a better fix but there was no further inquiry after.

Is there an updated fix to this where I can still receive Windows Updates? Especially since my main antivrus/antimalware is Windows Defender and its Security Intelligence gets new definitions from Windows Updates.

Comment: When having access to windows, you can create a new user and log in using the new user profile after a reboot. The first time it may take while as the new profile will be created, but after that you can try if the new user has the same problem. That might show if it's an issue with this installation or just your user profile.

Comment: That sounds a lot like something is causing the [Windows Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell) to not load or the Windows Shell is hanging - to verify, press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Esc` _(if that doesn't load Task Manager, press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Del`)_,. Is `explorer.exe` running under _Windows Processes_? If so, right-click → Restart || if not, Start a new process → `explorer.exe` . Does the Windows Shell load? Even with identifying whether it is the Windows Shell or not, it's going to be more efficient _(take less time)_ to simply do a Repair Install _(@John's answer)_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is almost for sure not a Windows Update issue. I have both real and virtual Windows 10 machines fully up to date with all updates and no black screen or sign on issues.

> DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth and sfc /scannow did
> not solve the issue. Issue does not present itself in Safe Mode.

**(1) Try a Windows 10 Repair Install** starting with Keep Everything.

> Go to the Windows Media Creation Link
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally
> answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

If Repair with Keep Everything does not work, then your system has either a damaged Windows 10 User Profile, or, more serious OS damage.

(**2) In either case,** the best solution at this point is to completely back up and **reinstall Windows fresh.**

Comment: I have an option to update to Windows 11. Would updating to Windows 11 have the same effect as Windows 10 Repair Install with Keep Everything?

Comment: It depends. If an App issue, then upgrading to Windows 11 may work like a Repair. So that part of my answer applies. If a profile issue, then not likely (my part 2)

Comment: Thanks! I will try updating to Windows 11 and if the issue persists I will reinstall Windows fresh.
Is there any big chance this is a malware? If I do reinstall Windows fresh and backup my files, I am worried that my files that I backup and copy to the fresh installed Windows will bring the malware over.

Comment: You could put your documents on an external drive. Leave them out of Windows 11.  Once you have Windows 11 and Apps running, do a full online and offline scan with Windows Defender both of Windows 11 and the external drive of documents

Comment: The issue was resolved after updating to Windows 11. Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear.  Thanks.  The upgrade would do the equivalent of a Repair Install

Answer (score 1):

I've recently (2/2024) had this problem on Windows 11 Pro.  I tried everything I found on Google except factoryreset and reinstalling Windows, and nothing worked.  It did not seem tied to any specific Windows Update and all my graphics drivers are up to date.

I experience all the common symptoms: Black screen after login with mouse cursor.  I'm able to Ctrl-Alt-Delete and start Task Manager, but restarting Explorer doesn't help.  Most importantly, this problem only occurs for one user on this machine, and seems to be working fine for all other users. After waiting a really long time after logging in the affected user (~10 minutes) Explorer would come up and everything seems normal except the Task Bar doesn't appear.

The ultimate solution was to log in as a different user that has administrator privileges and completely remove the affected user, and recreate an account for this user.  So far everything has been good now.

I've since went through and created local administrator accounts on all our other Windows 11 systems so I'm able to log in and delete and recreate users if this ever happens again.

Comment: I am on the same page except in my case it takes an hour or more despite having a really good hardware. Will try out this user solution that you have provided. It is still painful as I will have to reconfigure most of the user specific settings but that said at least it is better than a complete reset.

Comment: Another thing I have observed post restart is that the login creates a couple of Virtual Desktops - not sure if you are facing the same thing as well. My issues started once started getting this security log full warning and I could never get rid of those unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating the 'Shell' value under 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' in the Registry Editor to 'explorer.exe'.[reneelab](https://www.reneelab.com/fix-windows-10-black-screen-after-login.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: after the latest February 2024 Windows 10 update (22H2), the screen would stay black after login in with my user. The desktop would only show up after about 5 minutes.

I applied a solution found on this site: https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-black-screen-after-sign-in/

**The solution that worked for me** was to disable fast boot. I know that fast boot keeps a hibernation-like copy of the memory state of the OS on-disk. Obviously, this memory image was incompatible after the 22H2 update.

Now login-in is normal again. I haven't turned on fast boot. The speed difference, for me, is minimal.