I let Windows repair drive, but on boot met with black screen afterwards. Why?
I was rebooting Windows 10 then was met with the "To skip disk checking, press any key within xx second(s)" message. Now usually I just hit a key to skip past that but today I decided to let it happen. Then after that I was met with a black screen where I could only move my cursor. I've rebooted multiple times and this still hasn't changed.
I've tried booting into safe mode, but when I do that, my monitor loses signal, but the computer is still running as I can hear the fans. Running diagnostics via boot menu also detects nothing.

Your disk has died? Take it to a repair shop.

Try booting from USB and performing drive repairs. There are tools such as Hirens's BootCD PE, https://www.hirensbootcd.org, and many alternatives: https://alternativeto.net/software/hiren39s-bootcd/

Related, if not for a dupe https://superuser.com/questions/1803925/need-better-fix-for-black-screen-after-signing-in-to-windows - the repair install sounds like a good idea here

@JourneymanGeek Yeah I was thinking the same thing. I commented the question as if it was my issue but it's actually my friends. I just wanted a second opinion. I'll try and make a bootable usb. Thanks!
P.S.
Sorry for the wait time.
